# How to limit the Token based Authentication to a specific area of the site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, owin

I've implemented a token based authentication on a website. Now I need to add some legacy code, probably in some other area of the site, which is not token aware at the client side.

How can I limit the effect of `UseOAuthBearerTokens` method to a specific area of the site?

Thanks

Comment: How do you handle authentication now (attributes, global filters, etc..?)

Comment: These specific areas should be authorized?

Comment: Yes, they need complete Authentication and Authorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that the answer is that we can have webapi controllers to use token-based auth, while Mvc controlles still use cookie-based Auth, as instructed [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20974096/742775)

I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

you may create an AuthenticateHandler and set the logic there.