# Bearer authentication scheme with MVC page requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, jwt, bearer-token, cookie-authentication

Am using bearer authentication scheme to secure my webApp which built with angularjs for frontend and Asp.net webApi for backend and it works great with me. 
I modifided the $http service to add common authentication header "JWT token". 
Now new parts are added to the web project which using aspnet MVC controllers- views.
now if the http request is "Page request" not ajax request, the autherization header never added to the request header. 
I need some mechanism to inject the JWT token in authorization header if the request is PAGE REQUEST
Any suggestions??
Thanks!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953738/using-bearer-tokens-and-cookie-authentication-together